# init select2 Yii 2.0: yii2-widgets

Tags: php, jquery-select2, yii-extensions, yii2

I've this code

```
echo Select2::widget([
    'model' => implode(', ', ["ROME","NY"]),
    'name' => 'city',
    'options' => [
        'id'=>'city',
        'placeholder' => 'select a city ...',
        'class'=>'form-control'
     ],
     'pluginOptions' => [
         'tags' => $city,
         'maximumInputLength' => 4,
     ],
 ]);
```

my js file

```
 $('#city').on('change',function(x){
    $.ajax({
        url: '?r=markermap/setmarkerajax',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'city':x.val},
        success: function(res){
            setMarkers(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Plugin works when i select a city. Into controller i store into session values and want when reload or came back into page set again old value.
With this plugin how can do?
Into page i read that support $model , but i've session and not model object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = ["red", "green", "white", "black", "purple", "cyan"];
// without model
echo Select2::widget([
  'name' => 'category',
  'value' => "green,red", // value to initialize

  'options'=> [],
  'pluginOptions' => [
    'tags' => $data,
    'maximumInputLength' => 4,
  ],

]);

?>
```